# Most efficient way to query time series data by intervals

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have millions of documents like this (corresponding to time series data):

```
{
   "time_stamp": Date(...),
   "speed": X,
   "height: Y
   ...
}
```

So, one way of representing them would be in the time axis:

```
-a--b--c-d---e-f-g-----h...
```

And I want to query them grouped by intervals (each interval is represented by `|---|`):

```
|-a-|-b-|-c-|d--|-e-|f-g|---|--h|...
```

So that the result of the query would be:

```
[
  { _id: interval1, avgOfSpeedForDocumentsOfThisInterval: X, avg... },
  { _id: interval2, avgOfSpeedForDocumentsOfThisInterval: X, avg... },
  { _id: interval3, avgOfSpeedForDocumentsOfThisInterval: X, avg... },
  { _id: interval4, avgOfSpeedForDocumentsOfThisInterval: X, avg... },
  ...
]
```

The most efficient approach I've found so far is using the `$cond` operator in an `aggregation`:

```
[
  {
    $project: {
      timestamp: "$timestamp"
    }   
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        $cond: [
          // Here the conditions; each one defining one interval
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

But it doesn't seem that efficient and has a limitation of 50 intervals.

**Is there any canonical way to make this query in an efficient way?**

Comment: can you show some example documents/data and expected results.

Comment: @turivishal sure! updated.